# why some Routes not working after localization

Tags: laravel

can you any one tell me , is there any error, here I attach codes and error massage

```
<a href="{{ route('OnlineReply', [app()->getLocale(),'status' => 'Published']) }}" class="text-decoration-none">
```

Route

```
Route::get('/OnlineReply', 'OnlineReplyController@admin')->name('OnlineReply');
```

Error massage

> Route [OnlineReply] not defined.
>   (View:/home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/resources/views/admin/admindash.blade.php)

Comment: Are you sure your routes file is loaded? Did you add a dd() statement in it to make sure it is?

Comment: yes, I add DD(),

Comment: Can you try the route without the second argument? `{{ route('OnlineReply') }}`

Comment: <a href="{{ route('OnlineReply', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="text-decoration-none"> I have to run like this due to localization , error is like this {Route [OnlineReply] not defined. (View: /home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/resources/views/admin/admindash.blade.php)}

Comment: I try like this also ,{{ route('OnlineReply') }}, error is same

Comment: dear I try like this ,<a href="{{ url('OnlineReply', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="text-decoration-none"> then its Run, No error , I dont is that systematically right, but running

Comment: but there is another error, after adding second parameter its not running, this is code> <a href="{{ url('OnlineReply', app()->getLocale(),'status' => 'Published']) }}" class="text-decoration-none"> and this is error >syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' (View: /home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/resources/views/admin/admindash.blade.php)

Comment: That's because you forgot to open the array. `<a href="{{ url('OnlineReply', [app()->getLocale(),'status' => 'Published']) }}" class="text-decoration-none">` It still doesn't right though

Comment: i fixed that , but now showing  404 not found error